# How to beat GRUB2 into submission?

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, boot-loader

I have tried GRUB2 on different Ubuntu releases (12.04 and 13.04) on several machines and no matter what I do I can't get it to behave. It seems like a great idea (abstracting away configuration files through a CLI), but it really does not work for me.

Here's a simple example:

```
$ grub-set-default 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-45-generic'
$ grub-editenv list
saved_entry=Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-45-generic
$ update-grub && reboot
#.... wait for reboot....
$ uname -r
3.8.0-29-generic
```

I've tried editing `/etc/default/grub` as well as `grub-reboot`, and adding `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved` but with zero success. I normally end up shuffling the order of configuration files in `/etc/grub.d` to do what I need. Obviously, editing a `menu.lst` was much preferred to this shenanigans.

Has anyone had any of these features work? Did it take any tricks? I find it hard to believe that this could be broken this horribly and I feel that I'm clearly missing something.

Comment: Just use Syslinux...

Comment: Is it possible to script (i.e. not using sed or perl) booting into different kernels using syslinux? I'm looking to switch back and forth from Xen programmatically.

Comment: @jasonwryan Heresy! Use `lilo`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - I miss `lilo`, reminds me of my much simpler slackware days

Comment: Syslinux has very simple configuration files (unlike the Grub bloat): I don't know what you want to achieve, but if you can do it with Grub but not with Syslinux I would be very surprised.

Comment: Have you tried using an integer (like 2 or something, whatever position your preferred menu entry has) as the default? Maybe the string matching with `Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-45-generic` somehow doesn't work...?

Comment: @MartinvonWittich sounds right. It looks like they might not be checking the entire entry's name but are stopping at the first match. Zje, try using a number instead, that should work.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried a number in the past, but that number was '14' and did not work. However, a lower-ordered number (e.g. '2') does work. This lines up with the first-match hypothesis. I generally try to stay away from using numbers to avoid the non-determinism inherent with using automatically enumerated identifiers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I never had much luck with the abstracted configurations, mainly due to my lvm + mdadm setup and not updating my kernel the "distro way".  Luckily, you can ditch all of that and roll your own `grub.cfg` very similar to how `menu.lst` worked.

A sample `grub.cfg` that is excerpted from mine is:

```
set timeout=15

menuentry 'Linux 3.10.17 (sde) kernel-3.10.17-g' {
  root=hd0,1
  linux /boot/kernel-3.10.17-g domdadm dolvm root=/dev/md3
  initrd /boot/initrd-3.10.17-g
}

menuentry 'Linux 3.10.17 (sdf) kernel-3.10.17-g' {
  root=hd1,1
  linux /boot/kernel-3.10.17-g domdadm dolvm root=/dev/md3
  initrd /boot/initrd-3.10.17-g
}
```

The biggest differences from grub-legacy is how `root=` is specified, the `menuentry` specification and the keyword change from `kernel` to `linux` to specify the kernel.  If you have a `menu.lst` that works for you, you can easily adapt it to work as `grub.cfg` by addressing those changes.  If you need any of the extra functionality of grub2 (loading grub modules, etc), you can grab relevant lines from the distro scripts and add them to your file.

Comment: Thanks! I'm now trying to find a way to incorporate this into `/etc/grub.d` as this is a shared machine and I don't want someone clobbering my config by updating the kernel, etc...

Answer (score 0):

@casey's answer inspired me to come up with this solution based on the empty `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file (the only difference being that my file is prefixed to come first):

```
$ cat /etc/grub.d/06_zje
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
#Copied this idea from 40_custom
menuentry 'Ubuntu 12.04.3, with Linux 3.5.0-45-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
  recordfail
  gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
  insmod gzio
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ext2
  linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-45-generic root=UUID=be201df4-2268-419a-92ea-fd123a5acdef ro
  initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-45-generic
}
```

It's total hackery, but I can then change my boot order programmatically using a script the executes these commands:

```
ln -sf /etc/grub.d/06_zje /etc/grub.d/01_first && update-grub
```

For different OSes, I created different files in `/etc/grub.d`, e.g. `/etc/grub.d/07_xen`